# python3 mysql connector module throws exception - ValueError: Could not process parameters

Tags: python, mysql

I am trying to get past this error that is haunting me. I built a simple script to populate a single column database.

```
import mysql.connector

mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
  host="localhost",
  user="root",
  passwd="password",
  database="mydatabase"
) 
mycursor = mydb.cursor()

mycursor.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS data(pass_word VARCHAR(20))")

val = 'test'
sql = "INSERT INTO data(pass_word) VALUES '%s'"
mycursor.execute(sql, (val))
mydb.commit()
```

It creates the table no problem, so I know the connector is working. But it refuses to insert the val into pass_word.

It throws the following exception

```
Press ENTER or type command to continue
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "sql-try.py", line 19, in <module>
    mycursor.execute(sql, (val))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/mysql/connector/cursor_cext.py", line 248, in execute
    prepared = self._cnx.prepare_for_mysql(params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/mysql/connector/connection_cext.py", line 538, in prepare_for_mysql
    raise ValueError("Could not process parameters")
ValueError: Could not process parameters
```

Comment: did you try `mycursor.execute(sql, (val, ))`? if i remeber correctly you need to pass a list/tuple. without that comma, `(val)` is just a string...

Comment: I changed it like you suggsted and now I get a new error - _mysql_connector.MySQLInterfaceError: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '''test''' at line 1 - I also get this error now - mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '''test''' at line 1
slightly different...

Comment: @hiroprotagonist thank your help.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think the issue was that my table only had one column, so when I was passing the val, val itself needed to be a tuple. Changing it to (sql, (val,)) did not address the issue. When I created a table with more than one column, the problem went away.

```
mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
  host="localhost",
  user="root",
  passwd="password",
  database="mydatabase"
)
mycursor = mydb.cursor()
myname = 'jimmy'
password = 'grizwald'

mycursor.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS data3(my_name VARCHAR(20), pass_word VARCHAR(20))")

val = (myname, password )
sql = "INSERT INTO data3(my_name, pass_word) VALUES (%s, %s)"
mycursor.execute(sql, val)
mydb.commit()
```